# GCP Pub/sub: using goroutines to make multiple subscriber running in one application

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub

I have found a strange behaviour when receiving message from GCP Pub/Sub.
Following codes are how I register the subscriptions using [pubsub client](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub?tab=doc)

**gcp.go**

```
package gcp

import (
    "context"
    "path"
    "runtime"

    "google.golang.org/api/option"

    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
)

// PubsubClient is the GCP pubsub service client.
var PubsubClient *pubsub.Client

// Initialize initializes GCP client service using the environment.
func Initialize(env, projectName string) error {
    var err error
    ctx := context.Background()
    credentialOpt := option.WithCredentialsFile(getFilePathByEnv(env))

    PubsubClient, err = pubsub.NewClient(ctx, projectName, credentialOpt)
    return err
}

// GetTopic returns the specified topic in GCP pub/sub service and create it if it not exist.
func GetTopic(topicName string) (*pubsub.Topic, error) {
    topic := PubsubClient.Topic(topicName)
    ctx := context.Background()
    isTopicExist, err := topic.Exists(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        return topic, err
    }

    if !isTopicExist {
        ctx = context.Background()
        topic, err = PubsubClient.CreateTopic(ctx, topicName)
    }

    return topic, err
}

// GetSubscription returns the specified subscription in GCP pub/sub service and creates it if it not exist.
func GetSubscription(subName string, topic *pubsub.Topic) (*pubsub.Subscription, error) {
    sub := PubsubClient.Subscription(subName)
    ctx := context.Background()
    isSubExist, err := sub.Exists(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        return sub, err
    }

    if !isSubExist {
        ctx = context.Background()
        sub, err = PubsubClient.CreateSubscription(ctx, subName, pubsub.SubscriptionConfig{Topic: topic})
    }

    return sub, err
}

func getFilePathByEnv(env string) string {
    _, filename, _, _ := runtime.Caller(1)

    switch env {
    case "local":
        return path.Join(path.Dir(filename), "local.json")
    case "development":
        return path.Join(path.Dir(filename), "development.json")
    case "staging":
        return path.Join(path.Dir(filename), "staging.json")
    case "production":
        return path.Join(path.Dir(filename), "production.json")
    default:
        return path.Join(path.Dir(filename), "local.json")
    }
}
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "runtime/debug"
    "runtime/pprof"
    "time"

    "rpriambudi/pubsub-receiver/gcp"

    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
)

func main() {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":4001", Route()))
}

func Route() *chi.Mux {
    InitializeSubscription()
    chiRoute := chi.NewRouter()

    chiRoute.Route("/api", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Get("/_count", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Number of goroutines: %v", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        })

        r.Get("/_stack", getStackTraceHandler)
    })

    return chiRoute
}

func InitializeSubscription() {
    gcp.Initialize("local", "fifth-bonbon-277102")

    go pubsubHandler("test-topic-1", "test-topic-1-subs")
    go pubsubHandler("test-topic-2", "test-topic-2-subs")
    go pubsubHandler("test-topic-3", "test-topic-3-subs")
    // ....

    return
}

func getStackTraceHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    stack := debug.Stack()
    w.Write(stack)

    pprof.Lookup("goroutine").WriteTo(w, 2)
}

func pubsubHandler(topicID string, subscriptionID string) {
    topic, err := gcp.GetTopic(topicID)
    fmt.Println("topic: ", topic)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed get topic: ", err)
        return
    }

    sub, err := gcp.GetSubscription(subscriptionID, topic)
    fmt.Println("subscription: ", sub)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Get subscription err: ", err)
        return
    }

    err = sub.Receive(context.Background(), func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
        messageHandler(subscriptionID, ctx, msg)
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("receive error: ", err)
    }
}

func messageHandler(subscriptionID string, ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("recovered from panic.")
            msg.Ack()
        }
    }()

    fmt.Println("message of subscription: ", subscriptionID)
    fmt.Println("Message ID: ", string(msg.ID))
    fmt.Println("Message received: ", string(msg.Data))

    msg.Ack()
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}
```

It works great when i just have a few of `pubsubHandler` inside the `InitializeSubscription`. But when I adding more `pubsubHandler` inside the initialize function (approx 10 or more handler), things starting got interesting. The ack never reach the pubsub server, making the message is simply not ack-ed (I have checked the `AcknowledgeRequest` in metrics explorer, and no ack request coming). Thus, the message is keep coming back to the subscriber. Also, when i restart the application, sometimes it won't receive any message, neither new or an un-acked ones.

I seems to find a workaround by set the `NumGoroutines` to `1` for each subscription object in the `pubsubHandler` function.

```
func pubsubHandler(topicID string, subscriptionID string) {
    ....

    sub, err := gcp.GetSubscription(subscriptionID, topic)
    
    ....

    sub.ReceiverSettings.NumGoroutines = 1
    err = sub.Receive(context.Background(), func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message) {
        messageHandler(subscriptionID, ctx, msg)
    })

    ....
}
```

My question is, is this an intended behaviour? What is the root cause that may lead to those unexpected behaviours? Or my implementations is simply wrong, to achieve the intended results? (multiple subscription inside one application). Or is there any best practices to follow when creating a subscription handler?

In my understanding, the `Receive` function from `pubsub.Subscription` is a blocking code natively. Hence, when I tried to run it inside a goroutines, it may lead to an unexpected side effects, especially if we're not limiting the number of goroutines that may handle the messages. Is my reasoning a  valid one?

Thank you for your answers, and have a good day!

**Edit 1**: Updating the example to a full code, since the pubsub client is not directly imported in the main.go before.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue might be the rate at which you are handling messages (currently 10 seconds per message). If you receive too many messages at once, your client might be overwhelmed, which will lead to a buildup of a backlog of messages.

I recommend playing around with [flow control settings](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub?tab=doc#ReceiveSettings) and increasing `ReceiveSettings.NumGoroutines` to something higher than the default of 10. If your publish rate is high, you could also increase MaxOutstandingMessages, or completely disable the limit by setting it to -1. This tells the client to hold onto more messages at once, a limit that is shared per `Receive` call.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Because I sent the ack before `time.Sleep`, shouldn't the handling rate is less than 10 seconds per message? And also, if I increase `ReceiveSettings.NumGoroutines` does that means the number of goroutines which will handle _each_ message will increase, or that was the maximum number of goroutines spawned which will handle _any_ incoming message?

Comment: Usually, you want to do the bulk of your processing prior to  `ack`ing. Since you have the `time.Sleep` in your handle func, the message will still be held until the function returns. Increasing `NumGoroutines` increases the number of goroutines spawned to pull messages. If you want more goroutines to handle message, increase `MaxOutstandingMessages`.